# Comparing Column's with other columns with vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following problem to solve.

I have an excel sheet with 3 columns and 29000 rows.

Column a is an index number.

Column b is an id number.

Column c is a number which points to an index of column a

So if column c is 200. I need to go to column a 200 and take it's column b id and put it on the same row as the column c index.

The purpose of this is to link the id number of two items, who are linked by this column c.

(I hope I am making sense :/ )

So I have been trying to code this in VBA. At the moment I am using a nested for loop, but as you can imagine, the run time is pretty long....

```
dim i as integer
dim v as integer
dim temp as integer
i = 1
v=1

for i = 1 to 29000
   if cells(i,3).value > 0 then
    temp = cells(i,3).Value
     cells(i,5).value = cells(1,2).value
     for v = 1 to 29000
       if cells(v,1).value = temp and cells(i,5).value <> cells(v,2).value then
            cells(i,6).value  = cells(v,2).value
       end if
      next
    end if
 next
```

So it does work and performs what I want, but the run time is just too long. Any ideas how to streamline the program?

I am pretty new to vba and programming in general.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show a quick sample of what your result should look like.  I'm having a little trouble understanding what moves where.

Comment: Load all of your data into a variant array (`arr = Range("A1:F29000".Value`). Do all the operations on that array, then dump it back to the sheet (`Range("A1:F29000".Value = arr`). That will make it faster, but it would be better to avoid that looping by using dictionary lookups where you can.

Comment: so, the value in column C - is that the data you are trying to find in column A ? or is it the row number? also, do you need to do this in VBA, or would a formula be acceptable?

Comment: Yes a Formula would be fine to use. Column A is an index number. So the location in the list. The list has had objects taken out of it and put in over time. The problem this has caused is that some of the values in column C have been made redundant, as they point to the location on the list in column A, but these numbers have changed because things above and below an object have been removed or added. Tim, thanks for that answer, its runtime is really quick but have a logic error with it. I get the same value into column four and five all the way down. So I guess the variable is not changing?

Comment: Oh and also the contents of the variable is the very first item of column two and the very first instance where column 3 is greater than zero.

Comment: Found the logic error! Cells(1,2).Value should be Cells(i,2).Value. I tried to edit your post but I guess I am too new to these parts. Your code runs really smoothly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Last comment I promise. If you have time I would love for you to explain the code you gave a bit to me for my own education. In ley mans terms, what is it that you are doing differently to my original code and why is it that it runs so much quicker. It will help me understand the language as a whole I think. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but compiled OK

```
Sub Test()

Dim dict As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim temp As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim oldcalc

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Set dict = GetMap(sht.Range("A1:B29000"))

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        oldcalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    For i = 1 To 29000
       If Cells(i, 3).Value > 0 Then
            temp = Cells(i, 3).Value
            Cells(i, 5).Value = Cells(1, 2).Value
            If dict.exists(temp) Then
               If sht.Cells(i, 5).Value <> dict(temp) Then
                   sht.Cells(i, 6).Value = dict(temp)
               End If
            End If
        End If
     Next

     With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = oldcalc 'restore previous setting
     End With

End Sub

Function GetMap(rng As Range) As Object
    Dim rv As Object, arr, r As Long, numRows As Long
    Set rv = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") 'EDITED to add Set
    arr = rng.Value
    numRows = UBound(arr, 1)
    For r = 1 To numRows
        If Not rv.exists(arr(r, 1)) Then
            rv.Add arr(r, 1), arr(r, 2)
        End If
    Next r
    Set GetMap = rv
End Function
```